# My website loads very slowly and I don't know why

Tags: wordpress, https, elementor

My website loads very slowly and I don't know why.

The browser gets 'stuck' when visiting the site for the first time.

https://www.strevers.be

Comment: works fine on my end

Comment: looks fine to me here as well : https://tools.pingdom.com/#5ccdff7aacc00000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here. But if you want it faster then:

1. Use a caching plugin like wp-fastest cache
2. Use a CDN like cloudflare
3. Use an image optimiation plugin